# How to structure an Email and SMS sending web app that runs in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I need to develop a web application in asp.net and C# that sends emails and SMS. I already have a console version of this app that i created a few years back but it relies on a windows scheduled task, and is outdated.

What is the proper or best way to do this using asp.net, considering that i'll have other applications that will feed a database with the information to send. How can i setup a background service that will monitor this database and send the messages even if there are no pages open?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have control over the server where you want to run your application you can build a windows service. But without knowing more details this is just an opinion

Comment: i dont think you should use a asp.net application to do this task. you can develope a c# console application and set a cron job /  scheduled task in your server and run in after regular intervals of time. but you have to make sure that your database has a flag whether the email/sms was sent for the entry in the table

Answer (score 0):

We use Topshelf to run as a windows service and Quarts to schedule/manage the recurring job/function calls. Hangfire was another solution that looked interesting.

Hangfire
An easy way to perform background processing in .NET and .NET Core applications. No Windows Service or separate process required.

https://www.hangfire.io/